# How to pass variables to new window using Javascript and postMessage

Tags: javascript, html

I have a button in my homepage that opens to a new window FindAPark.html. I'm trying to pass a variable to that HTML page without GET.

I've tried this in my Homepage.js:

```
function buttonClick() {
    var newWindow = window.open('FindAPark.html');
    newWindow.my_special_setting = "Hello World";
}
```

And then in my FindAPark.js:

```
window.my_special_setting;
console.log(window.my_special_setting);
```

The console says it's "undefined" instead of showing "Hello World". What might be the problem, and what might fix it?

EDIT: Now it's telling me "Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "null" from accessing a cross-origin frame." I haven't hosted these on a domain yet, but I own both HTML files. What do I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use localStorage like this:

```
function buttonClick() {
     localStorage.setItem("mySepcialSetting", "Hello World");
     window.location.href = "FindApark.html";
 }
```

Then you can access it as follows:

```
var mySpecialSetting = localStorage.getItem("mySepcialSetting");
console.log(mySpcialSetting);
```

Comment: That did the trick! If I were to host this website, would this work on other people's computers as well?

Comment: Yes it will work, localStorage stores data in the user's browser.

Answer (score 2):

Use window.postmessage

In the opened window

```
window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);

function receiveMessage(event) {

 console.log(event)

  // ...
}
```

Now dispatch the event from the parent window

```
newwindow.postMessage("The user is 'bob' and the password is 'secret'",
                  "https://secure.example.net");
```

Comment: My console was empty when I did this. How do I access the message in my opened window and print that into the console?

Answer (score 0):

Provided your opened window is from the same security domain, you can pass the variable like you did in your question, but you should wait for the new window to completely load.

```
let newWindow = window.open('FindAPark.html');
newWindow.addEventListener('load', function(){
  newWindow.my_special_setting = "Hello World";
}, false);
```

Another option is to read a variable from the window that opens the new window... same security policies apply as above.

```
let my_special_setting = window.opener.my_special_setting;
```